# to find a pattern in a line and print the line

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a tab delimited file that looks like this:

```
chr1    28563   .   A   G   13.0    .   DP=3;VDB=3.520000e-02;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,0,2;MQ=25;FQ=-33;EFF=exon_variant(MODIFIER|||n.50+758T>C|WASH7P||NON_CODING|NR_024540.1|1)    GT:PL:GQ    1/1:44,6,0:9
chr1    537678  .   T   C   35.8    .   DP=2;VDB=6.880000e-02;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,0,2;MQ=37;FQ=-33;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:67,6,0:10
chr1    537680  .   G   T   28.8    .   DP=2;VDB=6.880000e-02;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,0,2;MQ=37;FQ=-33;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:60,6,0:10
chr1    540975  .   G   A   6.2 .   DP=7;VDB=3.422171e-02;RPB=1.053122e+00;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=2,1,2,1;MQ=19;FQ=7.43;PV4=1,0.34,0.19,1;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)    GT:PL:GQ    0/1:35,0,39:35
```

If any of the rows EFF=exon, the row should be printed.

```
chr1    28563   .   A   G   13.0    .   DP=3;VDB=3.520000e-02;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,0,2;MQ=25;FQ=-33;EFF=exon_variant(MODIFIER|||n.50+758T>C|WASH7P||NON_CODING|NR_024540.1|1)    GT:PL:GQ    1/1:44,6,0:9
```

Kindly help, with a one liner in bash or perl.
Thank you

In my case this line should be printed

Comment: `grep EFF=exon file`

Comment: @mpapec it should be an answer, IMO, the right way to go.

Comment: @Kent this question should be closed as it has many duplicates.

Comment: This is something you'd literally learn in the first hour of the first class you took on UNIX or the first chapter of a book, or the first page of a web site. And what you'd learn is that this is a job for grep, not awk.

Comment: It may sound rude, but this is a typical example of lmgtfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below awk command,

```
awk '/EFF=exon/{print}' file
```

OR

```
$ awk '/EFF=exon/' file
chr1    28563   .   A   G   13.0    .   DP=3;VDB=3.520000e-02;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,0,2;MQ=25;FQ=-33;EFF=exon_variant(MODIFIER|||n.50+758T>C|WASH7P||NON_CODING|NR_024540.1|1)    GT:PL:GQ    1/1:44,6,0:9
```